# issue deploying asp.net mvc 5 to iis server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, web-deployment

I am trying to publish / deploy my site to a iis 7 server.

When I click run in visual studio it works perfectly.

I followed a tutorial to use the web deploy to my server. the files are there and everything seems ok.

but when I go to the site:  `http://10.0.0.12:8000/`

I get: `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden`, `The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.`

I have given the site administrator credentials. And I checked there are default pages configured.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Here is my config File:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
 <appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
 <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
 </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What version of IIS do you use?

Comment: Did you install MVC on the machine? Did you set all handlers properly in your web.config? Is the right application running under the right path? Etc.

Comment: Install mvc on the machine? Please elaborate? According to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963307/how-to-install-asp-net-mvc-5-on-a-server you don't need to install

Answer (score 9):

Things to try and check:

1. Set the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"`attribute on the `<modules>` section in your web.config:

   ```
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
   ```
2. The website is configured to use an Application Pool using ASP.NET 4.0, Integrated Pipeline mode
3. ASP.NET 4.0 is registered in IIS. Use the following command to ensure this is the case (might need to adjust the `Framework64` folder with `Framework` if you are on a 32 bit server):

   ```
   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -ir
   ```

Comment: Oh my goodness. I don't know why this was so difficult. Your #3 saved me.

Comment: Thank you so much Drain your #3 made my day Thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Go to the web.config at the wed sites physical deployed locationand open it 
And you will find a an xml tag, almost at the end of the xml file, as the following content

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
               ....
    </handlers>
  <!--ENTER THE CODE HERE-->
  </system.webServer>
```

At the given location add the following code piece save and refresh ur site

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Also Try removing any othere  tags already available!