# how to update .net framework 3.5 to 4.0 for IIS7?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

i put my asp.net project on IIS7 but it gives error that .net framework 3.5 is not a targeted framework. i downloaded and installed framework 4.0 but still doesn't work. what could be the problem??

Comment: Create an application pool (in not exist) in iis for .net 4 and bind it with your  app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET 4.5 has not been registered on the Web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749138/asp-net-4-5-has-not-been-registered-on-the-web-server)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new application pool for Framework 4. Set application pool of your website to this new one. Se below link how to create application pool.
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731784(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731784%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

And Also don't forget to start framework 4.0.