# how to configure asp.net with .net 4.5

Tags: asp.net

I am using **visual studio 2012 ultimate**. Every time I open **asp.net web form application** the following message pops up.
`Configuring web http://"localhost":35651/ for ASP.NET 4.5 failed.`

You must manually configure this site for `ASP.NET 4.5` in order for the site to run correctly`. ASP.NET 4.5` has not been registered on the `Web server`. You need to manually configure your `Web server` for `ASP.NET 4.5` in order for you site to run correctly.

How to get rid of this message ?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873126/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server

Answer (score 22):

You can install this update and your problem should be solved:
[MSDN link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6.aspx)

Update:
I've uploaded the file to my Dropbox account so that people can have alternative URL in case if the first one fails, The File Name is VS11-KB3002339.exe

Comment: can you add update version/file names, in case link goes down in future?

Comment: I would advice not to download this from someones private dropbox due to virus risks.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 which wouldn't support the aspnet_regiis -i approach.

Go to **Control Panel**, Click On **Programs** locate the **"Turn Windows features on or off"** option Under **Programs and Features** and drill down as follows:

**Internet Information Services** -> **World Wide Web Services** -> **Application Development Features** and check the **"ASP.NET 4.5"** option. In checking this box, other options such as ".NET Extensibility 4.5" and the ISAPI options will be checked automatically.

Apply the changes by clicking OK. Restart your System.

Comment: This was such an odd problem, but I guess that is because this device hadn't been configured entirely, as its IIS was completely off. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use aspnet_regiis.exe -i. Only you need to set the path of .net version. See this link for more information

[ASP.NET 4.5 has not been registered on the Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749138/asp-net-4-5-has-not-been-registered-on-the-web-server)

Answer (score 0):

***FOR VISUAL STUDIO 2012***

you actually need to download an update to fix it from here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3002339

Description:
Unexpected dialog box appears when you open projects in Visual Studio 2012 after you install the .NET Framework 4.5.3

Reference from related thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49746751/3261852