# ASP.NET 4.5 is not registering on the web server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting the errors below when trying to open existing and when trying to create a new MVC 4 web app. with VS 2012 on a Win 7 x64. Searching on SO I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749138/asp-net-4-5-has-not-been-registered-on-the-web-server) which seems to be what I'm looking for. But after running the command "successfully" it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Existing Project
[image]

New Project
[image]

IIS
[image]

Comment: do you have .net 4.5 installed?

Comment: It looks like it. Is there another way to check besides looking at IIS?

Comment: Looking in my registry. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\1033` 4.0 is the TargetVersion and 4.5.53349 is the Version

Comment: Have you tried removing IIS and then adding it back? That solved my issue when I faced the problem you're facing

Comment: @Izzy I just tried it, no luck

Comment: After I added it back I ran the following command `"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

Comment: Thanks but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to register framework to IIS:

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319->aspnet_regiis –ir
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate ASP.NET 4.5 on IIS. This is done through "Turn Windows Features on or off". Type this in your Start Menu and navigate through the tree as following:
Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features -> ASP.NET.

Check the box named ASP.NET and it should work. Depending on your operating system it may also show ASP.NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the help. I ended up re installing .NET 4.5 using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wf8YTe_4HQ0) video.
After it was uninstalled I had to run a repair on VS 12, it wasn't finding .NET 4.5 
But it now works again.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2012, I downloaded the Microsoft update found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3002339

Information found on:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6/