# ASP.NET 4.5 has not been registered after installing windows 10

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, windows-10

After upgrading to Windows 10, I started getting this error:

> ASP.NET 4.5 has not been registered on the Web server. You need to
>   manually configure your Web server for ASP.NET 4.5 in order for your
>   site to run correctly.

I searched on it and found this link [ASP.NET 4.5 has not been registered on the Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749138/asp-net-4-5-has-not-been-registered-on-the-web-server)

I tried the accepted answer.

Unfortunately, on Windows 10, this doesn't work. It'll respond with:

> Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0 Administration
>   utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. Start
>   installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0). This option is not supported on this
>   version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead
>   install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows
>   Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the
>   dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771. Finished installing
>   ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).

After this I opened  **Programs and Features** window, hit the "Turn Windows Features on or off" in the left pane.

I click on

> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> 
>       Application Development Features

But I can't see there ASP.NET 4.5 option.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 9):

Just for your information this error message doesn't really affect anything, it has no impact on your project. Anyway, Microsoft has published a fix for all impacted versions of Microsoft Visual Studio.

- Visual Studio 2013: Download Visual Studio 2013 Update 5: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48129
- Visual Studio 2012: An update to address this issue for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 has been published - KB3002339, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3002339. Direct download link here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/0/2/A02C37E0-77F7-448A-BD5C-F66AB1F78DBC/VS11-KB3002339.exe
- Visual Studio 2010 SP1: An update to address this issue for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 has been published - KB3002340, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3002340. Direct download link here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/7/E/67E041A1-00DA-4948-90BE-75A0146C08F5/VS10SP1-KB3002340-x86.exe

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hit this problem with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 10 and can confirm that KB update does indeed fix it