# IIS 7.5 ASP.NET area missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

im trying to load my project in the Local IIS Server but when i configure and browse i get the following message

> Service Unavailable
>   HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

FYI: When i change the configuration in Visual Studio in presents a message saying "ASP.NET 4.5 has not been registered on the Web Server. You need to manually configure your webserver for ASP.NET 4.5"

What can i do?

[Visual Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePF5A.png)

[When trying to browse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Ac9.png)

Comment: Have you checked the application pool settings?

Comment: Yes, i dont see anything wrong there

Comment: did you try this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749138/asp-net-4-5-has-not-been-registered-on-the-web-server

Comment: Yep, also tried that, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the command : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i